# SFTP in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, sftp

I need to execute the SFTP process through C# code. I am using Windows service. Below is the code I am using.

```
WebCash.writeToFile(WebCash.outerbatchpath, command);
WebCash.writeToFile(WebCash.outerbatchpath, "exit");

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c "+WebCash.outerbatchpath);
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

psi = null;
WebCash.writeToFile(WebCash.GetErrorLog(), DateTime.Now.ToString() + "- Running SFTP end - " + p.ExitCode);
return p.ExitCode;
```

While trying to debug the above code the debugger is not able to pass `p.WaitforExit()` function(i.e) service is not executing after `p.WaitforExit()`.

I am running the below command(SFTP) in my outerbatch.

```
 psftp -b D:\Source_Data\SFTP\innerbatch.bat -l username -i D:\privatekey.ppk @servername
```

Inner batch contains the below command

```
put D:\Source_Data\SFTP\FileToTransfer.xml
```

I need the exit code also to get the error. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the program you are running (the "outer batch") never finishes.

When you redirect a process output, you must be reading it. There's a limited buffer for the redirected output. When it fills, the child process stops on the next attempt to produce an output and waits until the parent process reads some data from the buffer. As you never do and you wait for the process to exit, deadlock occurs.

See the MSDN for the [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput) :

> Synchronous read operations introduce a dependency between the caller reading from the StandardOutput stream and the child process writing to that stream. These dependencies can cause deadlock conditions. When the caller reads from the redirected stream of a child process, it is dependent on the child. The caller waits for the read operation until the child writes to the stream or closes the stream. When the child process writes enough data to fill its redirected stream, it is dependent on the parent. The child process waits for the next write operation until the parent reads from the full stream or closes the stream. The deadlock condition results when the caller and child process wait for each other to complete an operation, and neither can continue. You can avoid deadlocks by evaluating dependencies between the caller and child process.

It's always recommended to use the `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` instead of the `p.WaitForExit()` in this case. Both commands wait for a process to exit, but the first ensures the deadlock does not occur.

On the other hand, as you are transferring only one file, I'm not sure the `psftp` output is actually large enough to fill the buffer. If the above suggestion does not help, I'd recommend you to simplify the code by directly running the `psftp.exe`, removing unnecessary layers of the `cmd.exe` and the outer batch file.

EDIT: If you never run `psftp` under a service account, it is possibly prompting for host key confirmation.

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
>   have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
>   think it is.
>   The server's dss key fingerprint is:
>   ssh-dss 1024 0b:77:8b:68:f4:45:b1:3c:87:ad:5c:be:3b:c5:72:78
>   If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
>   PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
>   If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
>   If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
>   connection.
>   Store key in cache? (y/n)

You should use the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to explicitly specify a fingerprint of the trusted hostkey.

Alternatively use some native SFTP .NET library.

Side note: Naming the `psftp` script `.bat` is confusing. It's not a (Windows) batch file.

Comment: Changing the p.WaitForExit() to p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() is not working. Same result :(

Comment: OK, than it's likely due to some prompt, see my edit.

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this other than using WinSCP library. Because i need to change the full code and i don't have enough time. Also i have only private key to connect to server but for WinSCP we need to pass the password and SshHostKeyFingerprint.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you need to copy the host key cache to the service account registry. For WinSCP: It supports private key too (`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath`). Regarding `SshHostKeyFingerprint`: Any decent SFTP/SSH library requires you to provide/verify host key. It's a crucial security feature. See [Verifying the Host Key](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key) and also [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint for use with scripting or .NET assembly?](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_hostkey).

Comment: I have identified the problem. My windows service is running on Local machine account. I have the keys registered in HKEY_CURRENT_USER. But since my Windows Service is running on Local machine account it should be cached in HKEY_USER. It can be done manually. But is there any other way to do while the service starts to run.

Comment: Ideally the service should not have an access to your user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, so (hopefully) this should not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using WinSCP.

For `SshHostKeyFingerprint` see [Server and Protocol Information Dialog](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_fsinfo)

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "000.00.00.000",
    UserName = "xxxxxx",
    Password = "xxxxxx",
    PortNumber= 22,
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload files
    //TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    //transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    //TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    var results = session.ListDirectory("/path");
    foreach (RemoteFileInfo item in results.Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }

    // Throw on any error
    //transferResult.Check();

    // Print results
    //foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
    //}
}
```

Comment: sessionOptions has parameters Password, SshHostKeyFingerprint. How to get that. I have only private key to access the server(i.e) I have Servername, Username and private key to access the server. Pls help..

Comment: to get your server SshHostKeyFingerprint: just run winScp client "windows app", add user name/ password, the app will display that key, or you can open the WinScp app, from Commands menu-> Sever/ Protocol information-> the pop up window contains that key.